# NuGet package wont appear in references

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I am trying to install a NuGet Package from a private package source, and whenever I try to install or update a specific package, it doesn't appear in the project's references folder in Visual Studio.

The `packages.config` file says it is installed, but it isn't listed in the references. Has anyone else had this issue? Does anyone know how to fix it?

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise on a Windows 8.1 machine.

Comment: You could try `update-package -reinstall` in the package manager console for that project

Comment: @bump I've just tried that. Still getting the exact same result. NuGet is still saying that it is still installed when it isn't.

Comment: You could add a reference to the DLL in a package by hand

Comment: @bump What I've ended up doing is adding the project files into my solution and adding a reference that way. It's defiantly not ideal and definitely isn't a fix. But thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Is this package custom? If not, could you share us the package name to us?

Comment: @Leo-MSFT Its a package which is privately used by the company I work at.

Comment: @SamBunting: When installing a package, does it appear in your `packages` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your reply to the comment, The reason for this problem should be related to your privately package. You can verify it by installing a common package from NuGet.org, like Newtonsoft.Json, check if it add the reference after install the package.

Not very sure that how you create that privately package, I would like provide a simple workaround to test it:

1. Download the [NuGet Package Explorer](https://npe.codeplex.com/downloads/get/clickOnce/NuGetPackageExplorer.application).
2. Open the NuGet Package Explorer, select the create a new package.
3. Add a lib folder on the content tab, and add your dll file
4. Save the package and install it to the project, check if it add reference.

[image]

Hope this can help you.